# Symfony NelmioApiDocBundle : Attributs And Normalizer

Tags: php, symfony, nelmioapidocbundle

I've nested objects :

```php
class Review{
  #[Groups(['read'])]
  public int id;
  #[Groups(['read'])]
  public string author;
  /**
  * @var Comment[] comments
  */
  public array comments;
}
class Comment{
  public string lang;
  public string comment;
}
```

I use this `Review` object as response for an api route.

I have a normalizer that replace `comments` from `Review` by a `comment` string (the comment in desire language) so the response of my route is an JSON object like :

```
{
  id:3,
  author:'Philip',
  comment:'Good comment'
}
```

I use attributs to describe the route's return :

```
#[OA\Response(
    response: 200,
    description: 'Return a review',
    content: new OA\JsonContent(ref: new Model(type: Review::class,groups: ['read']))
)]
```

The `comment` property is missing in the description of the response, is there a way to add it ?